# NuxtJS axios post to cockpit CMS

Tags: vue.js, axios, fetch, nuxt.js, cockpit-cms

I'm currently building a nuxtjs project with cockpit as my headless CMS. Currently I find an issue in using axios for submitting the post data. When using the following fetch it's working as intended:

```
fetch('/api/forms/submit/Inschrijven?token=xxxtokenxxx', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({
       form: {
            author: 'John Doe',
            content: 'Something',
            published: true
        }
    })
});
```

But sadly fetch isn't supported by IE, a browser which is required by this project. Therefor we are using axios for our requests but using axios.post on the same url as above always returns 'Path not found'.

```
axios.post('/api/forms/submit/Inschrijven?token=xxtokenxx', {
    author: 'John Doe',
    content: 'Something',
    published: true
})
.then(entry => entry.json())
.then(entry => console.log(entry));
```

I suspect there is something wrong in the API which doesn't recognises this as a genuine json post. Anybody here has a clue on why the axios.post doesn't work?

Comment: are you setting an axios baseURL?

Comment: Yes this is done!

Answer (score 0):

I previously worked with cockpit cms and nuxtjs and i can say a couple of things are different from how you made your request.

1. You failed to pass the headers
2. Use JSON.stringify

   `axios.post(
       'https://something.com/api/forms/submit/contact?token=XXX',
       JSON.stringify({
         form: {
           name: this.name,
           model: this.carModel,
           service: this.service,
           number: this.models.phoneNumber
         }
       }),
       {
         headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
         }
       }
     )`

   Similar to the example on [the docs](https://getcockpit.com/documentation/api/forms)

   `fetch('/api/forms/submit/cockpitForm?token=xxtokenxx', {
       method: 'post',
       headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
       body: JSON.stringify({
           form: {
               field1: 'value1',
               field2: 'value2'
           }
       })
      })
      .then(entry => entry.json())
      .then(entry => console.log(entry));`